# Quickly opening files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

One particualar feature that I liked the most and I absoultely need from Visual Assist X is the quick file opening shortcut. Instead of browsing through solution explorer each time I want to open a file, I want to simplt type the file name to see it pop open. This was possible with Visual Assist X, and I do not want to pay the high price just for this feature.

Is there any other way to do this with other tools?

Comment: <crtl>, and then start typing the file name

Comment: type in the littte box above solution explorer that says 'search solution explorere' - thats <ctrl>;

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn320181.aspx#BKMK_Search